# Shell: Using function with parameters in if

Tags: bash, shell, function, arguments

I'm trying to execute the code below but when I try to use my function in the if statement I get the `-bash: [: too many arguments` error.
Why is it happening?

Thank you in advance!

```
notContainsElement () {
  local e match="$1"
  shift
  for e; do [[ "$e" == "$match" ]] && return 1; done
  return 0
}

list=( "pears" "apples" "bananas" "oranges" )
blacklist=( "oranges" "apples" )
docheck=1

for fruit in "${list[@]}"
do
    if [ notContainsElement "$fruit" "${blacklist[@]}" -a $docheck = 1 ]
    then
        echo $fruit
    fi
done
```

Comment: Use http://shellcheck.net/ (or its offline version). It finds the issue mentioned in the answers albeit with a far less detailed explanation and without a solution.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When using `if [ ... ]` you are actually using the `[` utility (which is the same as `test` but requires that the last argument is `]`).

`[` does not understand to run your function, it expects strings.  Fortunately, you don't need to use `[` at all here (for the function at least):

```
if [ "$docheck" -eq 1 ] && notContainsElement "$fruit" "${blacklist[@]}"; then
  ...
fi
```

Note that I'm also checking the integer first, so that we may avoid calling the function at all if `$docheck` is not 1.

This works because `if` takes an arbitrary command and decides what to do from the exit status of that command.  Here we use a `[ ... ]` test together with a call to your function, with `&&` in-between, creating a compound command. The compound command's exit status would be true if both the `[ ... ]` test and the function returned zero as their exit statuses, signalling success.

As a style note, I would not have the function test whether the array does *not* contain the element but whether if *does* contain the element, and then

```
if [ "$docheck" -eq 1 ] && ! contains "$fruit" "${blacklist[@]}"; then ...
```

Having a function test a negative will mess up logic in cases where you *do* want to test whether the array contains the element (`if ! notContainsElement ...`).

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer and the other pieces of advice!

Answer (score 3):

try

```
if notContainsElement "$fruit" "${blacklist[@]}" && test "$docheck" = 1
then
```

- <s>`-a` option is neither a shell or a `test` option</s>

here you have two part test

```
notContainsElement "$fruit" "${blacklist[@]}"
test $docheck = 1 ## or [ $docheck = 1 ]
```

you link then in `if` using

```
if cmd1 && cmd2
```

as pointed out `-a` is a test option, but can only be used with other test option, thus you can use

```
if [ "$a" -lt "$b" -a "$a" -lt "$c" ]
```

to test that `$a` is lower than both `$b` and `$c`, but you cannot used other command within test scope.

Comment: arg, @Kusalananda was fastest gun in world wild web again ;)

Comment: RSI is the price I pay for that.

Comment: `-a` is *test* option, it means AND.

Comment: @hyde Except it has been marked obsolescent in the POSIX standard.

Comment: It is obsolete only because it is not recommended to be used since complex expressions are subject to problems in case that parameters are expanded shell variables. Since `test` is built into shells since the early 1980s, it is not slower but more reliable to use `&&`and `||` together with more `test`calls. Note that in the mid 1980s, it took one second to call the external `test` utility and this is why people liked to see complex `test` expressions.

Comment: @Archemar, ...consider fixing the quoting bugs still present in your examples (unquoted `$docheck`, unquoted `$a`/`$b`/etc in the last example).

Comment: I quoted variable, because **thou shall quotest thy variables** how when OP set docheck to numerical value, or if I know that a b,c are numerical, I don't see the point

Comment: @Archemar Unquoted numerical strings would still be susceptible to word splitting if a mischievous user sets `IFS` so that it includes digits.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative that some people may not like. Convert your blacklist array to a string, and see if the string with a fruit removed is the same. Edited to pad the strings with spaces. Thanks to Scott for pointing out the apple/pineapple problem.

```
badlist=" ${blacklist[@]} "
for f in "${list[@]}"
do
    if [[ "${badlist/" $f "/}" == "$badlist" ]]
    then
        echo "$f"
    fi
done
```

I think this is simpler, but lacks the && logic which many prefer.

Comment: (1) This fails in the case that one of the `list` fruits is *contained within* one of the `blacklist` fruits.  For example, if we change `blacklist` to `( "oranges" "pineapples" )`, the output of your script doesn’t change. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (2) I don’t quite understand what you mean by “I think this is simpler, but lacks the && logic which many prefer.”  It’s often easier to make things simpler by leaving out functionality.  As [Albert Einstein may or may not have said,](https://quoteinvestigator.com/2011/05/13/einstein-simple/) “Everything should be made as simple as possible, but no simpler.”  Why did you leave out the `&&`?  (3) When you post code, please indent it appropriately.

Comment: Well, I tried to use the 4-space indent but it seems that it didn't work. I see what you mean about the pineapples, though.

Comment: It also can't distinguish between a single list entry `two words`, and two subsequent items, `two` and `words`. And if your list contained `*` as an entry, it would match everything. (And because you aren't quoting the `$f` in what should be `echo "$f"`, if you *did* try to echo such an element, it would be replaced with a list of filenames in the current directory).

Comment: I've made some edits. This is not trivial when the data in the arrays is arbitrary. Suppose "apples" is in the blacklist and "Granny Smith apples" is an element of the other array. I think the OP's code has similar issues. The arrays have to be made of elements that "work."